# How can I solve my boot error with Natty and btrfs?

Tags: 11.04, boot, grub2, btrfs, initramfs

I'm getting this boot error on Natty:

```
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found.  Try passing init= bootarg.
```

The root system is using btrfs. However, when I boot up a live-CD, I can mount the system partition without any problems and there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with it.

Running btrfsck gives this output:

```
sudo btrfsck /dev/md0p1 
found 33322205184 bytes used err is 0
total csum bytes: 32134752
total tree bytes: 401801216
total fs tree bytes: 334020608
btree space waste bytes: 104869496
file data blocks allocated: 38219010048
 referenced 33116684288
Btrfs Btrfs v0.19
```

I hope someone can help me out with this problem.

Comment: Those are the result of the root fs not being mounted.  Look at the lines above there to see why.

Answer (score 1):

Does this still happen with the newest version of GRUB in Natty (1.99~rc1-13ubuntu3)?  I backported a number of btrfs-related fixes from upstream in the period since you asked your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug about the bootloader and not the btrfs partiotion itself. I haven't tested natty using btrfs as root, but I read about GRUB having issues mounting btrfs as root...
Maybe try to use a separate /boot partion for the boot...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I do have a separate boot partition (/dev/sdc1).

Comment: Have you been able to boot (at least one time) after the installation or never?

Comment: Yes, the installation booted fine. It just stopped working this morning. There was no power outage and the system halted cleanly last night.

Comment: does your /etc/fstab looks ok?